# Does there exist such an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I aim to find out an affine scheme $X$ such that satisfies:

1 $X$ is irreducible.

2 $\exists f\in\mathcal O(X)$ such that $X\setminus Z_f$ is neither irreducible nor empty.

I have stuck on it for quite a while so that I wonder if such an example exists...

If such an $X$ exists, may I please ask for some examples? Is there any way to construct such an example? Or if it does not exist, may I please ask why?

Thanks for any answers, hints or references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irreducible means " every two non-void open subsets intersect", that is "every non-void open subset is dense" . From this, one sees right away that this passes down to open subsets: every open non-void subspace of an irreducible subspace is irreducible.

Therefore, you can't find such an example

Comment: May I please ask for some explaination on "this passes down to open subsets(open subschemes?)" that why every open non-empty subscheme of a irreducible subscheme is irreducible? It is harder then I expected... I tried to prove: Suppose $X\setminus Z_f$ is not irreducible, then $X$ is not but stuck. May I please ask for how to see it?

Comment: @PropositionX: Take two non-empty open subsets of $X\backslash Z_f$. They will also be open in $X$, since $X\backslash Z_f$ is open. So they will intersect. That's all.